# Segmentation fault on WSL during Laravel installation

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, sails.js, laravel-sail

I'm using WSL with Ububtu and Docker installed.
Trying to install Laravel using command:

`curl -s https://laravel.build/test-project | bash`

After some minutes the installation interrupt with errors:

```
...
242.6 Setting up build-essential (12.9ubuntu3) ...
242.6 Setting up debhelper (13.6ubuntu1) ...
242.6 Setting up pkg-php-tools (1.42build1) ...
242.6 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.4) ...
242.7 Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5) ...
242.8 Processing triggers for php8.2-cli (8.2.13-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
242.8 Segmentation fault
243.1 curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

I don't know how to solve this problem

I've followed this guide:

[https://blog.devgenius.io/kickstart-your-laravel-web-app-using-laravel-sail-30276265e588](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Where is your project stored at?